# Select the rows that just inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

How can I retrieve the row just inserted?

```
INSERT INTO LETTRE_VOIT
select rsVoit.NOID, NO_ORDRE, rsOrdre.CODE_DEST, rsOrdre.MODAL_MODE, rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT,
CASE rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT
            WHEN 'false' THEN 'D'
            ELSE 'P'
        END, 
rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS,
CASE rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS
            WHEN 'false' THEN 'L'
            ELSE 'E'
        END, 
  rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE, LIBELLE, NBR_COLIS,POID,ENLEV_CREMB,ENLEV_DECL
from ORDRE rsOrdre
inner join
(
  select CODE_DEST,MODAL_MODE, MODAL_PORT, LIVRS_EXPRS,ENLEV_UNITE, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CODE_DEST) as NOID
  from ORDRE
  group by CODE_DEST,MODAL_MODE,MODAL_PORT,LIVRS_EXPRS,ENLEV_UNITE
) rsVoit on rsVoit.CODE_DEST = rsOrdre.CODE_DEST and rsVoit.MODAL_MODE = rsOrdre.MODAL_MODE
and rsVoit.MODAL_PORT = rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT and rsVoit.LIVRS_EXPRS = rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS
and rsVoit.ENLEV_UNITE = rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE

LEFT JOIN T_UNITE ON rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE = T_UNITE.NOID
WHERE (STATUT_ORDRE = 3) AND IS_PRINT = 'false' AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (SELECT ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@Trans)))
order by rsVoit.NOID, NO_ORDRE

SELECT * FROM LETTRE_VOIT WHERE ???
```

For example:

I inserted 2, it return 2

and then I inserted 3, I want return 3 instead of 5 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Stev

PS: May be I need to use a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you want back.... but SQL Server has an `OUTPUT` clause that can output stuff from `INSERT` and `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(col1, col2, ..., colN)
OUTPUT Inserted.Col1, Inserted.IDCol, Inserted.Col17
VALUES(val1, val2, ...., valN)
```

Here, you're inserting values and the inserted values for the `IDCol` (e.g. an INT IDENTITY column), `Col1` and `Col17`.

If just getting back the results into your grid in Mgmt Studio is good enough - then use the `OUTPUT` clause! Read more [about the `OUTPUT` clause on Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server

And you know how many row inserted then go through

```
SELECT top 2 * FROM LETTRE_VOIT order by primaryKeyId desc
```

put the number of row inserted at place of `2`.

It may be help you, If you know the number of inserted rows, and then you can provide the numbers with top keyword

Comment: not bad idee, the problem i don't know how many row inserted. that mean i have make to SQL : 1. to insert and return how many row inserted 2. SELECT TOP

Comment: Then go through, @coconut answer

Comment: This won't work unless you know exactly how many rows you're inserting (can't use a variable in TOP).

Comment: This is not a good idea. It may work in most cases, but there is no guarantee that the returned rows will be the same as the ones inserted.

Answer (score 2):

How about saving the records in a variable before inserting them or adding a date field and retrieve them by date?