# How to see what rows were added with Django connection.cursor.execute()?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have this python code ...

```
    sql = """
INSERT INTO app_table(...cols..) 
SELECT DISTINCT ... cols ... FROM app_temptable e 
WHERE something = 'Generic' AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT id FROM app_table u WHERE e.somethingelse = u.somethingelse);
    """
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            log.info( '%s rows inserted.' % cursor.rowcount)
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                print(row)
    except Exception as ex:
        err = ex
        log.error("sql: %s" % sql)
        raise err
```

... it prints the row count and then throws the exception:

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: not a query
```

I guess because I wasn't doing a select.  But the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/) says to get the affected rows call 
`cursor.fetchall()`.

So how do I get the affected/rows inserted?
I am using a Oracle database.

It says it here:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `cursor.fetchall()` only applies to `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Yeah ... I kind of got that part.  My question is how do I get the rows that were inserted?

Comment: Depending on what database you are using, you can `SELECT` the returned values in an `INSERT`.  For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342425/select-the-rows-that-just-inserted)

Comment: This can't really be answered without seeing your exact query.

Comment: You can get the total number of affected rows (`cursor.rowcount`) but I believe in order to access the rows themselves you will need to issue a separate `SELECT`.

Comment: @Celeb Goodman.  I have added the full query to the question.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using an oracle db.